# How to evaluate functions substituted by a regex in Julia?

Tags: regex, string, julia

Say I got a (possibly long) string containing matches for some regex. I would like to be able to call a non-trivial Julia function on all the matches and substitute the output in the string.

For example, let the regex be `\|[0-9]+\|` and the computation function be `f(x) = x^2`.

```
This is a string containing |1| and |4|.
```

I would like to obtain as a result

```
This is a string containing 1 and 16.
```

My question is: how can I implement this?
Note that it would be nice if the code works for different regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `replace` function:

```
julia> s = "This is a string containing |1| and |4|."
"This is a string containing |1| and |4|."

julia> replace(s, r"\|[0-9]+\|" => x -> parse(Int, chop(x,  head=1, tail=1)) ^ 2)
"This is a string containing 1 and 16."
```

In general in the signature of `replace` that has the form:

```
replace(s::AbstractString, pat=>r; [count::Integer])
```

note that `pat` can be a `Regex`, and `r` can be a function taking the match as an argument.